# Possible/Feasible to download parcel map and add up to 20 layers

Tags: layers, maps, parcel

Novice who just downloaded and installed QGIS a few minutes ago. Currently reading about the functionality of QGIS but thought that I may be able to obtain immediate insight in reference to my objective.

Is it possible to use QGIS to download parcel maps from a internet site and then add up to 20 custom layers?

Specifically, my objective is to download a parcel map for a particular city with "basic" attributes such as:

- Parcel Outlines
- Zip codes
- Hydrography
- Highways/Freeways

Then, I would like to have the ability to use the data within my MS Excel worksheet (worksheet 1) to create up to 20 custom layers for display on the parcel map and maybe color code the layers.

Layers could include metrics such as population, average age, median sales, etc.

Finally, I would like to display this map on a worksheet within my MS Excel workbook for presentation.

Is this even possible?

Comment: what format is the parcel data in?

Comment: Parcel data in the MS Excel worksheet is in the format similar to;

Comment: Monthly parcel data in the MS Excel worksheet (over 50,000 records) are in multiple columns; APN, Street Address, City, State, Zip code, latitude, longitude, Sale Date, Sale Price, etc.  Ideally, I would like to visually see the variances in the metrics - zipcode vs. zipcode more readily in a visual instead of viewing in a tabular format.

Comment: Just read about time series visualizations using another software.  Would be great if QGIS could perform this as well!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, what you want to achieve is totally possible. But the long answer is that in order to do this, you really require some basic knowledge of GIS and spatial data.

For starters, you don't really need to add layers of data more than you need to characterize and populate the data tables associated with your geometric data (the parcel outlines). Then, you'll be able to build symbologies for the variables you want to map.

I would recommend to start off with QGIS tutorials and then come back with more specific questions.

- [Importing csv data in QGIS](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html)
- [Joining table data to spatial
  data in QGIS](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html)